# Progress bar for loop does not appear until loop calculation is done

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having difficulty comprehending how progress bars work in the context of a loop. My example is as follows:

```
import time
from tkinter import ttk,Tk, Label, Button,Label,DoubleVar
MAX = 4

root = Tk()

root.title("My Progressbar")
root.geometry('500x500')

theLabel = Label(root, text="Progress")
theLabel.pack()

progress_var = DoubleVar() 
progress_var.set(0)
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=progress_var, 
length=400,maximum=MAX,mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack()


for i in range(MAX+1):
    print(i) #Where I will eventually do all my work. Here I print i and pause .5 sec
    time.sleep(.5)
    progress_var.set(i)
    root.update_idletasks()

# Add quit button
def _quit():
        root.quit()
        root.destroy()

quit_button = Button(master=root, text="Quit", bg='lightgray',command=_quit)
quit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm missing something obvious as the bar does not appear until after the loop is complete. Also, is it possible to indicate the % complete somewhere on the bar?

Answer (score 1):

You do the "work" before the flow of execution even has a chance to reach `root.mainloop`. You'll want to simulate doing the work after starting the mainloop. Maybe you could add a button which, upon being clicked, simulates the work? Try this:

```
# ...

def do_work():
    for i in range(MAX+1):
        print(i) #Where I will eventually do all my work. Here I print i and pause .5 sec
        time.sleep(.5)
        progress_var.set(i)
        root.update_idletasks()

# ...

do_work_button = Button(master=root, text="Do Work", command=do_work)
do_work_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, I should have expanded upon my example. In my ultimate application, there is a "do_work" function as you describe. I added "do_work" after my progressbar.pack()
 and before my quit button, but the same thing happens. Also, hitting "do_work" a second time does not "refresh" the progress bar.

Comment: Edit to above. Progress bar appears when I hit "do_work" but does not indicate gradual progress as loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only just want to increase the value in the progressbar each 0.5 second.Try this:

```
import time
from tkinter import ttk,Tk, Label, Button,Label,DoubleVar
MAX = 4

root = Tk()

root.title("My Progressbar")
root.geometry('500x500')

theLabel = Label(root, text="Progress")
theLabel.pack()

progress_var = DoubleVar()
progress_var.set(0)
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=progress_var,
length=400,maximum=MAX,mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack()

def add():
    if progress_var.get() < MAX:
        print(progress_var.get())
        progress_var.set(progress_var.get()+1)
    root.after(500, add)

# Add quit button
def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

quit_button = Button(master=root, text="Quit", bg='lightgray',command=_quit)
quit_button.pack()

root.after(500, add)

root.mainloop()
```

---

If it is a specific work, you need to create thread or process.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I'll need to create a thread or process as you indicate. Ultimately, I'm running  a script that involves a loop, which could take several hours to execute.